# Object.keys() is returning [] when passing a valid object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

At random times, calling Object.keys() for a VueX object is returning []. After console.log statements, the object is printed out properly with type object but when passing this variable to Object.keys, it is returning [].

`let obj = {2:{status: "good", tasks: Array(0), last_message: {…}, owner_name: "...", …}
 15:{status: "good", tasks: Array(0), recency: null, path: {…}, sublabel: "AE", …}
 54:{status: "good", tasks: Array(0), recency: null, path: {…}, sublabel: "AE", …}
 56:{status: "good", tasks: Array(0), recency: null, path: {…}, sublabel: "SJ- Account Executive", …}}`

`Object.keys(obj) ---> []`

Solution:
I had to use Vue.nextTick. Vue Components weren't being updated after store dispatch, this has fixed the issue.

Comment: You have to call `Object.keys(obj)` with the object as the parameter.

Comment: Looks like it's already working to me. Tried it with your snippet (after removing the ...'s), got `["2", "15", "54", "56"]`, which looks right. Can you add more context? Is the object you're getting the keys of actually declared with `let` as in the example, or does it come from somewhere else? Also, if you use a `for (let key in obj) { console.log(key) }`, do you get any logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you're using a framework that manages stateful objects with a server, I'd strongly suggest that this is just another *"AJAX is asynchronous"* issue. In other words, you're making a call to the server and expecting the call to block execution until the response comes back.

If so, it doesn't. You need to work with the object inside a callback function that runs when the data arrives.

Other potential possibilities are that the keys of the object are *non-enumerable* or they're all *inherited*. Those don't seem likely, but they would prevent `Object.keys` from including them.

Comment: I had to use `Vue.nextTick`. Vue Components weren't being updated after store dispatch, this has fixed the issue.